# Why do we need access interrupt while using passive queues?

Tags: networking, opnet

I am writing an assignment about OPNET active and passive queues in OPNET. I can't figure out why this is needed and what benefits it provides.

Answer (score 0):

Access interrupts are needed for passive queues because they do not have built in servers, thus they are raised from the destination process to force/access the passive queue and ask for the packet to be sent downwards towards the process, thus the name access interrupt.